# The POM for org.sonarsource.sonarqube:sonar-check-api:jar:7.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, sonarqube

I am a fresh in Sonar.When I try to use this example to write custom rules,the dependency "sonar-plugin-api" I see is version 6.7. But my Sonar's version is 7.0. I don't know what's the matter with the difference. So I download the SonarSource 7.0 to get the jar. But I get the following errors when I build the Maven project "sonar-plugin-api".

```
[INFO] os.detected.name: windows
[INFO] os.detected.arch: x86_64
[INFO] os.detected.version: 10.0
[INFO] os.detected.version.major: 10
[INFO] os.detected.version.minor: 0
[INFO] os.detected.classifier: windows-x86_64
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------- ---
[INFO] Building SonarQube :: Plugin API 7.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.sonarsource.sonarqube:sonar-check-api:jar:7.0- SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.sonarsource.sonarqube:sonar-duplications:jar:7.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.sonarsource.sonarqube:sonar-testing-harness:jar:7.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.468 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-05-16T18:41:47+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/121M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project sonar-plugin-api: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.sonarsource.sonarqube:sonar-plugin-api:jar:7.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.sonarsource.sonarqube:sonar-check-api:jar:7.0-SNAPSHOT, org.sonarsource.sonarqube:sonar-duplications:jar:7.0-SNAPSHOT, org.sonarsource.sonarqube:sonar-testing-harness:jar:7.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.sonarsource.sonarqube:sonar-check-api:jar:7.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are adding wrong libraries to the project. Refer this [Maven Sonar Api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sonarsource.sonarqube/sonar-plugin-api)  and add the required version of dependency in the pom file and execute `mvn clean install` instead adding jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Which example are you talking about ?

Your error is that you are building a submodule without building all the module of SonarQube. Go to your clone root and just do a `mvn install`.

Comment: Ah...It's "sonar-custom-plugin-example" in SonarSource.Building all the module will occur to out of memory.So I try to build one submodule...But I have already found the package from the other answer....Thanks.